# Event when we plug/unplug the ac cable

Tags: windows, events

I want to execute 2 bat file : 1 when the cable is unplgged and the other when the cable is plugged. But on windows, when I creat a task with the task scheduler on the event when the cable is unplugged, it also trigger when the cable is plugged back (The event is Kernel-Power id : 105). There is 2 soltuion : find 2 evenements that differeciate the plug and unplug of the alimentation or write a batch file that run with task scheduler with the event mentionned above and that differnciate when the cable is plug or unplug and execute different commande line.
Here are my lines for the cable pluged """

```
start C:\"Program Files (x86)\MSI Afterburner"\MSIAfterburner.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\12noon Display Changer\dc64cmd.exe" -quiet -depth=max -width=1920 -height=1080 -refresh=144
```

Here are my lines for the cable unpluged

```
taskkill /f /im MSIAfterburner.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\12noon Display Changer\dc64cmd.exe" -quiet -depth=max -width=1920 -height=1080 -refresh=60
```